# Why am I getting an import error when trying to use react-native-maps?

Tags: expo, react-native, react-native-maps

**Quick version:**

`expo init MyNewProject`

`cd MyNewProject`

`expo install react-native-maps`

add `import MapView from 'react-native-maps'` to the top of my App.js, save/reload and I get the following error screen, along with this warning in the Expo Dev Tools

> C:/Users/MyUser/Projects/current/MapTest/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/components/MapView.js
> Attempted import error: 'requireNativeComponent' is not exported from 'react-native-web/dist/index'.

:
[image: build error]

**Long Version:**

I created a brand new react-native app using expo, via `expo init MyNewProject` and chose a blank template. I then installed react-native-maps into my project directory as detailed here, https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/, by running `expo install react-native-maps`. At this point I haven't touched the code, other than adding an import in my App.js for the MapView component `import MapView from 'react-native-maps'`. Now, when I save/reload the app, it dies. What's happening?? Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

React Native Maps doesn’t support the web. You can use React Native Web Maps for the platform difference in the meantime.